# Weather web service for Europe?

Tags: web-services, rest, xml-rpc, provider, weather

We are looking for a reliable "current weather" web service for Europe, with city resolution. We only need the current weather.

Since it is for a commercial web site, we don't mind paying a reasonable fee for the service.

What are our options? What service would you recommend or avoid based on previous experience?

Note: SOAP Web Service, XML RPC, REST, all are fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The US NOAA has [coded METAR information](http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/observations/metar/stations/) available for cities worldwide. Given the ICAO airport code for the city in question (eg. [EGLL](http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/observations/metar/stations/EGLL.TXT) for London) you can quickly get a METAR report.

Answer (score 2):

[Weather Underground](http://www.wunderground.com/) is a successful weather site that cover most of the world. We've used their data sometimes at work. They offer weather [XML feeds and API](http://wiki.wunderground.com/index.php/API_-_XML) which includes access to current observations.

Comment: this service nice but not includes details about weather like humudity....

Answer (score 1):

http://www.weather2u.com provide a commercial service with global coverage. However they, like most global weather sites use model derived data from the NOAA National Weather Service, the accuracy of which compares unfavourably with local national weather services, especially for coastal regions.

Answer (score 1):

Get it direct from the UK's Meteorological Office. they provide [datafeeds](http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/newmedia/datafeed/catalogue.html) for the world in several formats. If you prefer european dedicated feeds (of which the UK provides data anyway), you want to check [ecomet](http://www.ecomet.eu/)

Answer (score 0):

I would use google weather feed ;) I have not found how to read it out but it clearly is great source [How to parse XML in JavaScript from Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323982/how-to-parse-xml-in-javascript-from-google)

Comment: This service is now deprecated as it was part of iGoogle.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to interface with [Yahoo weather Europe](http://weather.yahoo.com/Europe/EUROPEX/regional.html) like the team of the [weather plasmoid](http://www.kde-look.org/content/show.php/Weather+Plasmoid?content=84251) did.
Or if you only need to add it to a web page you could use directly [this gadget](http://www.gmodules.com/ig/creator?synd=open&url=http%3A//www.labpixies.com/campaigns/weather/weather.xml&pt=%26context%3Dd%26synd%3Dopen%26lang%3Den%26.lang%3Den%26country%3Dus%26.country%3Dus%26cat%3Dall%26num%3D1%26start%3D-1%26cols%3D1%26objs%3DOVJ&sn=OVJ&lang=en)

Comment: "The feeds are provided free of charge for use by individuals and non-profit organizations for personal, non-commercial uses. "