# Meteo info in win32 APP

Tags: delphi, vcl, weather

Is there a good meteorological tool to use in win32 DELPHI App ?

I did some googling but could not find anything good

Don’t need any complex data, just a simple 3/5 day forecast would be nice

Comment: There are a gazillion web services offering weather. Delphi can consume web services. That's where I'd start.

Comment: good question look forward to the answer myself.

Comment: Have you tried the services listed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108025/weather-web-service-for-europe

Comment: For US users,  try http://www.nws.noaa.gov/forecasts/xml/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at yahoo apis...
The weather api is great and very easy...

You can find a link at: http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/

Comment: do you have a link to some delphi headers or code that uses this api?

Comment: Look at this http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/ you must first get the yahooID ...